# SharePoint & Google OpenID Error (500)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, acs, azure-service-bus

Recently, I have had a small number of users getting a 500 error being server from the Azure Access Control service bus.

They are reaching out SharePoint application, being directed to Google to login, and then getting a very basic error message like below:

> ```
> An error occurred while processing your request.
>
> HTTP Error Code:  500
> Trace ID: 12922223-bfc1-47ab-9629-d398a83a115b
> Timestamp:    2017-01-27 12:06:05Z
> ```

Other users are not experiencing the issue, and I'm trying to see where I can view a log file to check the error.

Has anyone else had this?

Last year, I configured the Azure ACS to use Google and OpenID, and it's been fine up. I had an intermittant issue on the 11th Jan that said

> ```
> HTTP Error code: 502 
> Message: ACS40103 An error occurred while processing a Google sign-in response. 
> Open ID identifier 'open_id' was not returned from Google
> ```

But this went away the very next day for the user affected (I should note that I was able to login with no issues).

I cannot locate anything specific in the error logs to correlate this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.